# Powerpivot DAX - How to get the "Second from the Last" date

Tags: ssas, powerpivot, dax

In a dimension table of Period where there is a DateTime column, i need to get the "Second from the Last" date from that table. I need to use the result in a Filter expression which does not allow MAX() function.

I was able to get the lastest date and use it in filter with the following expression:

`FILTER(PeriodForecastEuro, RELATED(DimPeriod[PeriodDate]) = LASTDATE(VALUES(DimPeriod[PeriodDate])))`

But I have no idea how to get "the second from the last" and the "third from the last".

I am new to the entire SSAS thing. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
=Calculate(LASTDATE(Table[Date]), FILTER(Table, Table[Date]< LASTDATE(Table[Date])))
```

Comment: Explain how this helps. Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score -1):

LASTDATE(VALUES(DimPeriod[PeriodDate]))-1

Comment: David, consider adding some explanation to your response.

Comment: This is wrong: it returns the previous date from the last date in the table, not the previous EXISTING date. i.e. if the last two dates are: `2017/08/21`, `2017/08/17`, and the current selected date is `2017/08/21`, then the formula returns the value `2017/08/20`, and that's not what needed.